# Running sp_executesql query expects parameter @statement

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I'm not sure how to resolve this error:

*Procedure or Function 'sp_executesql' expects parameter '@statement', which was not supplied.*

for this query:

```
DECLARE @a INT 
DECLARE @b VARCHAR 
SET @a = 1

WHILE @a < 30
BEGIN
set @b = @a  
exec sp_executesql update source_temp set pmt_90_day = pmt_90_day + convert(money,'trans_total_'+@b)+N'
    N'where convert(datetime,'effective_date_'+@b)+N' <= dateadd(day,90,ORSA_CHARGE_OFF_DATE)
    and DRC_FLAG_'+@b = 'C'''

SET @a = @a + 1
END
```

Also, can you help me understand the proper usage of N' and if its done correctly in this statement.

Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "sp_executesql" stored proc expects a single string parameter @statement to execute.

Your string is totally out of whack here..... you need to prefix any "fixed" string parts with a N'......' to make them Unicode strings, but this is definitely not properly the case here.

I think you might want to try this:

```
DECLARE @a INT 
DECLARE @b VARCHAR(2)

SET @a = 1

DECLARE @statement NVARCHAR(500)

WHILE @a < 30
BEGIN
    SET @b = CAST(@a AS VARCHAR(2))

    SET @statement = 
        N'update source_temp set pmt_90_day = pmt_90_day + ' + 
             'convert(money, ''trans_total_' + @b + ''') ' + 
             'where convert(datetime, ''effective_date_' + @b + ''')' +
             ' <= DATEADD(DAY, 90, ORSA_CHARGE_OFF_DATE) ' +
             'and DRC_FLAG_' + @b + ' = ''C'''

    exec sp_executesql @statement

    SET @a = @a + 1
END
```

Does this work and do what you expect it to do??

Explanation: the N'.........' delimits the whole string which contains the SQL statement. Any apostrophe inside that has to be duplicated ("escaped"). I hope I understood your logic correctly.

Marc

Comment: I'm trying to run my update dynamically in a loop so each iteration updates the fields by an increment of 1. Its a reference from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753947/using-while-loop-for-sql-server-update

Comment: ex: iteration 1 uses effective_date_1, iteration2 uses effective_date_2, etc

Comment: Closer :D  getting this error Must declare the scalar variable @b, I don't know why since its declared up top

Comment: Phew - dynamic SQL is almost quite messy, especially if you try to "concat together" your field names and stuff.....

Comment: Painfully close.." Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'effective_date_' to data type int. "

Comment: Phew - this is long a long-distance jigsaw puzzle without seeing the pieces, just calling out what to do :-)

Comment: I know, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: So close.. " Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string. "

Comment: Well, but this seems like there's a probelm in you "effective_date_xxx" columns - are those really valid dates? All of them? Try running a "SELECT Effective_Date_1, CONVERT(DATETIME, Effective_Date_1)" and so on and see if all works - if not, fix your Effective_date column

Comment: Your right many of the outer effective date fields are empty so the convert evaluates to '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' How should I fix that?

Comment: Are the fields empty meaning "NULL"? In that case you could add an ISNULL(Effective_Date_x, some_default_date) clause to the statement

Comment: Or could you exclude all dates that are NULL ?? Just skip those rows?

Answer (score 1):

The sp expects a variable of type string, not a SQL statement. Wrap you SQL in single quotes:

```
 exec sp_executesql 'some SQL statement';
```

When you do that, escape any single quotes in the statement by replacing each single quote with two single quotes:

```
exec sp_executesql 'select 'AB' from dual';  -- wrong

exec sp_executesql 'select ''AB'' from dual';  -- right
```

I have no idea what `N` is. What do you think it is? Is it some sort of cast to a character set? Why do you think it's necessary?

Comment: The N'' denotes a UNICODE (NVARCHAR) string