# Sql Query Concatenation is not executing

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
USE [Test] Go
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_ViewAdvanceSearchDetails]
( 
 @JobStatus nvarchar(20)
)
AS BEGIN

DECLARE @SelectQuery nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @JobSeekerStatus nvarchar(20)

SET @SelectQuery= N'SELECT Tbl_JobSeekers.National_Id, Tbl_JobSeekers.JobSeeker_EnglishName, Tbl_JobSeekers.JobSeeker_Arabicname, Tbl_JobSeekers.Mobile, Tbl_JobSeekers.City, 
                  Tbl_JobSeekers.Nationality, Tbl_JobSeekers.Education, Tbl_JobSeekers.Experience, Tbl_JobSeekers.Category, Tbl_JobSeekers.JobSeekerStatus, 
                  Tbl_JobSeekers.StatusEmployer, Tbl_JobSeekers.ImagePath, Tbl_JobSeekers.ResumePath, Tbl_JobSeekers.Remarks, Tbl_JobSeekers.Created_By, 
                  Tbl_JobSeekers.Created_Date
                  FROM Tbl_JobSeekers INNER JOIN
                  Tbl_City ON Tbl_JobSeekers.City = Tbl_City.City_Name INNER JOIN
                  Tbl_Qualification ON Tbl_JobSeekers.Education = Tbl_Qualification.Education_Name INNER JOIN
                  Tbl_Categories ON Tbl_JobSeekers.Category = Tbl_Categories.Category_Name INNER JOIN
                  Tbl_Experience ON Tbl_JobSeekers.Experience = Tbl_Experience.Experience_Years'

SET @JobSeekerStatus=@JobStatus

IF (@JobSeekerStatus='Selected')
    BEGIN
        SET @SelectQuery= @SelectQuery + ' WHERE Tbl_JobSeekers.JobSeekerStatus=' + @JobSeekerStatus + ' ORDER BY Tbl_JobSeekers.National_Id DESC'
    END
ELSE IF (@JobSeekerStatus='Working')
    BEGIN
        SET @SelectQuery= @SelectQuery + ' WHERE Tbl_JobSeekers.JobSeekerStatus=' + @JobSeekerStatus + ' ORDER BY Tbl_JobSeekers.National_Id DESC'
    END
ELSE IF (@JobSeekerStatus='Looking')
    BEGIN
        SET @SelectQuery= @SelectQuery + ' WHERE Tbl_JobSeekers.JobSeekerStatus=' + @JobSeekerStatus + ' ORDER BY Tbl_JobSeekers.National_Id DESC'
    END
ELSE IF (@JobSeekerStatus='All')
    BEGIN
        SET @SelectQuery= @SelectQuery + ' WHERE Tbl_JobSeekers.JobSeekerStatus=' + @JobSeekerStatus + ' ORDER BY Tbl_JobSeekers.National_Id DESC'
    END
ELSE 
    BEGIN
        SET @SelectQuery= @SelectQuery + ' ORDER BY Tbl_JobSeekers.National_Id DESC'
    END

PRINT @SelectQuery

EXEC sp_executesql @SelectQuery, N'@JobSeekerStatus nvarchar(20)', @JobSeekerStatus

END
```

Hi All, Based on your suggestions ,I re corrected from Exec to EXEC sp_executesql and passing parameters as value, Query is still not executing showing error message "Invalid Column 'Selected' " (which i supposed to pass as parameter value). Whatever I am passing value, its showing invalid column with that paramenter.

Comment: This appears to be doable without needing dynamic SQL, is there a reason for this approach?

Comment: I suspect you need some extra quotes for your parameters if they are text

Comment: @Mihai, you are correct, the parameter passed is `@JobSeekerStatus='All'` however i'd recommend using sp_executesql and pass the variable as a parameter to it if dynamic sql is required here for some reason

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running sp\_executesql query expects parameter @statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756855/running-sp-executesql-query-expects-parameter-statement)

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the @JobSeekerStatus in 3 quotes

Updated to use QUOTENAME (thanks to ughai)

E.G

```
SET @SelectQuery= @SelectQuery + ' WHERE Tbl_JobSeekers.JobSeekerStatus=' + QUOTENAME(@JobSeekerStatus, '''') + ' ORDER BY Tbl_JobSeekers.National_Id DESC'
```

Comment: while your answer is correct, you should recommend to use `QUOTE_NAME` or even better use `sp_execuesql` with parameters

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all your suggestions , Its working fine.

My Modified Code:

```
  SET @SelectQuery= @SelectQuery + ' WHERE Tbl_JobSeekers.JobSeekerStatus='''+ @JobSeekerStatus +''' ORDER BY Tbl_JobSeekers.National_Id DESC'

  EXEC sp_executesql @SelectQuery, N'@JobSeekerStatus nvarchar(20)',@JobSeekerStatus
```

Answer (score 0):

See `sp_executesql` stored procedure in SQL Books Online.

Comment: `sp_executesql` will do the job. The author is asking about his error not the exact syntax.