# MS SQL - How to update local variable and have variable in WHERE condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server

currently I'm trying to update a local Variable using an UPDATE statement while also trying to cancel the UPDATE statement when the variable reaches a certain value:

```
UPDATE table
SET @var = @var + 1,
    field = @var
WHERE @var < 10
```

This unfortunately doesn't work since it runs for all records instead of just 10. Has anyone an idea how to elegantly solve this without using a loop? 
Thanks!

EDIT:
What I'm trying to do ist to allocate some kind of votes to parties. Say a party got 36.47% of the total votes. So I calculate a ratio of .47% (cutting of the integer part) for this party. Now I order my results table by ratio DESC and add one vote to each party as long as there are votes remaining. The remaining votes are stored in the variable. That's overly simplified but I hope you get what I want to do.

Comment: Actually what you are trying to do? Sample table data, and Desired output after Update would help to get quick solution

Comment: You'd need to write this as a WHILE loop instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753947/using-while-loop-for-sql-server-update

Comment: And in your code of Update you are updating the whole table.? Is it what you are trying to do?

Comment: SQL works with sets. An `UPDATE` operation acts "as if" all column values are computed in parallel and all rows are updated in parallel. As Shakeer says, a clear idea of what you're trying to do would help.

Answer (score 3):

You can probably achieve what you're trying to do by using [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql). Here's a basic example:

```
declare @t table (field int not null, Ord int not null)
insert into @t(field,Ord) values (0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(0,4),(0,5)

;With Numbered as (
    select
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Ord) as rn
    from
        @t
)
update Numbered
set field = rn
where rn < 4

select * from @t
```

Results:

```
field       Ord
----------- -----------
1           1
2           2
3           3
0           4
0           5
```

Here, the row numbers are being generated inside a [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) and using an appropriate column to make the ordering well-defined (as your edit suggests you have something similar available). We also take advantage that you can write an `UPDATE` against a CTE rather than the base table (provided the `UPDATE` clearly only attempts to update a single table)

Comment: Can you please explain why you are creating a table? Will op have to create a table aswell or did you create it for demonstration purposes only?

Comment: @gromit190 - I try to give examples that are complete rather than making people guess at what data I had. Had the OP supplied some sample data in the question (ideally also as `create table` and `insert` to help would-be answerers) I'd have copied their's in rather than having to make it up completely.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I was a little confused about whether the table "t" was necessary to solve OPs question.